# Puppeteer only runs three times on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, heroku, puppeteer

I'm working on a website which uses puppeteer to scrape data from another website. When I run the npm server on my local machine, it scrapes the data just fine, however when I deploy it to Heroku, it only runs the first three files I'm looking for and then stops.

I'm essentially trying to scrape data about classes from my school website, so I run this line in a for loop,

`let data = await crawler.scrapeData(classesTaken[i].code)`

This runs this function down below. I have replaced the actual website URL for my own privacy.

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
      ]
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    
    await page.goto("website url")
    await page.type('#crit-keyword', code)
    await page.click('#search-button')

    await page.waitForSelector(".result__headline")

    await page.click(".result__headline")

    await page.waitForSelector("div.text:nth-child(2)")

    let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let classTitle = document.querySelector("div.text:nth-child(2)").textContent
            .toLowerCase().split(' ')
            .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1)).join(' ').replace('Ii', "II")
        let classDesc =  document.querySelector(".section--description > div:nth-child(2)").textContent.replace('Lec/lab/rec.', '').trim()

        return {
            title: classTitle,
            desc: classDesc
        }
    })

    console.log(`== Finished grabbing ${code}`)

    return data
```

This runs perfectly fine on my own local server. However, when I push to my Heroku website, it only runs the first three class codes. I have a feeling this could be due to my dyno running out of memory, but I don't know how to make it wait for there to be available memory.

Here are the deploy logs

```
2023-05-22T17:29:18.421015+00:00 app[web.1]: == Finished grabbing CS 475
2023-05-22T17:29:19.098698+00:00 app[web.1]: == Finished grabbing CS 331
2023-05-22T17:29:19.783377+00:00 app[web.1]: == Finished grabbing CS 370

2023-05-22T17:29:49.992190+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/util.js:317

2023-05-22T17:29:49.992208+00:00 app[web.1]:     const timeoutError = new Errors_js_1.TimeoutError(`waiting for ${taskName} failed: timeout ${timeout}ms exceeded`);

2023-05-22T17:29:49.992209+00:00 app[web.1]:                          ^

2023-05-22T17:29:49.992209+00:00 app[web.1]: 

2023-05-22T17:29:49.992210+00:00 app[web.1]: TimeoutError: waiting for target failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

2023-05-22T17:29:49.992211+00:00 app[web.1]:     at waitWithTimeout (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/util.js:317:26)

2023-05-22T17:29:49.992230+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Browser.waitForTarget (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Browser.js:405:56)

2023-05-22T17:29:49.992230+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ChromeLauncher.launch (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:100:31)

2023-05-22T17:29:49.992230+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

2023-05-22T17:29:49.992231+00:00 app[web.1]:     at async Object.scrapeData (/app/crawler.js:9:21)

2023-05-22T17:29:49.992231+00:00 app[web.1]:     at async getClassData (file:///app/server.mjs:40:16)

2023-05-22T17:29:49.992234+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

I read somewhere to try clearing the build cache using these commands

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
$ heroku builds:cache:purge --app your-app-name
```

I have tried that and it didn't do anything. I also followed the [troubleshooting notes](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md) for Heroku on the puppeteer GitHub.

The reason I believe it might be something to do with my dyno memory is due to [this related post](https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack/issues/94). If this is the case, I would like to figure out how to wait until there is available memory to use.

EDIT: I am now running the browser in headless mode as well, this results in the exact same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further logging, I discovered the issue was that I was leaking memory by opening the browser and then never closing it. By adding the line `await browser.close()` right before the return statement of the `scrapeData()` function, the memory leaks stopped and the server was able to parse all of the class codes correctly.